# Using C# DLL in Python3 with Pythonnet

Tags: python, c#, clr, python.net

I'm using c# dll in Python3, and the module I'm using is  [DaveSkender/Stock.Indicators](https://github.com/DaveSkender/Stock.Indicators)
It is written in C# and complies with the Common Language Specification (CLS).
So I compiled it as dll
and imported in Python3 like below:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference(r'dll/Skender.Stock.Indicators')
```

Until now, It works and can be sure that module imported successfully.
But the problem is passing parameter.
There is a method like this in C# DLL:

```
public static IEnumerable<SmaResult> GetSma<TQuote>(
            IEnumerable<TQuote> history,
            int lookbackPeriod)
            where TQuote : IQuote
        {
            // WHATEVER
        }
```

So I passed the params in Python like this:

```
from System.Collections.Generic import List

// Definitely, Qoute is inherited from IQoute 
history_list = List[Qoute]()
Indicator.GetSma(history_list, int(1))
```

But it keeps showing TypeError:

```
TypeError: No method matches given arguments for GetSma: (<class 'System.Collections.Generic.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'>, <class 'int'>)
```

I don't know which type in Python is compatible with C#.
What should I pass in this method?
I mean what should I pass for IEnumerable in Python?

Comment: Maybe the other parameter? How is int defined in python?

Comment: And by the way you are showing the GetSmaExtended method but you are using (or trying to use) the GetSma method.

Comment: @Ralf Oh, Thank you for having interests on it. I fixed it but there's nothing different. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank to @Ralf, I looked inside C# code again about `GetSma()`. And it is Generic method, should be called in Generic form. So I tried to call this method like the below:

```
Indicator.GetSma[Qoute](history_list, int(1))
```

It works!! Hope this answer to be helpful if there is someone like me.